# Why set_cookie not setting a cookie and instead returning None in flask?

Tags: python, flask, cookies

I was trying to set a cookie in flask enviornment for my webapp but for some unknown reason the cookie is not being set and no error is being displayed. I have tried the same method before a year ago and it worked flawlessly but somehow it's not working anymore.

This code is written as a separate function in app.py file which is being called in other @app.route functions to get the user_id value.

**The Flask Debug Code**

```
user_id = None
user_id = request.cookies.get('nuid')
if user_id is None:
    response = make_response()
    print(user_id)
    response.set_cookie('nuid', value=cookie.nuid())
    print(cookie.nuid())
    user_id = request.cookies.get('nuid')
    print(user_id)
    return response
print(user_id)
return user_id
```

**The Output**

```
None
76fbacf3e38090f86acb7dcfd8b36da2
None
```

cookie.nuid() is a function created which will create a new random string. (This works perfectly no problems with this).

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone has a more precise answer than me, but from my experience any dictionaries inside the `request` object are immutable, which means you can not write to them. My guess would be that setting the cookie does not actually execute until request handler function exists. You will then see the cookie on the next request.

Edit:

The `request` object contains information about the request that came in from the client. When you call `user_id = request.cookies.get('nuid')` you are checking if the immutable dictionary `cookies` (which is an attribute of the `request` object) has the `'nuid'`key . It returns `None`, because the client did not send one in the request.

You are then creating a cookie and setting it to the `response` object, meaning that your response to the client will include the `nuid` key and the cookie as its value. However, that does not mean that the original request sent to you by the user contained the `nuid` key, so when you call `user_id = request.cookies.get('nuid')` it still returns `None`. **Once client's request has been parsed into the `request` object, the object can not be altered.**

If on the subsequent request the client choses to send you the back the cookie with they key `'nuid'` that you provided in the `response` object, then `user_id = request.cookies.get('nuid')` will return the value of the cookie.

Comment: We are not using dictionaries anywhere in the code, cookie.nuid() returns a string as shown in the output. "response.set_cookie('nuid', value=cookie.nuid())" This is the format to set the value of a cookie which expires at a defaut date automatically.

Comment: I appriciate the edited answer and understand what you are saying completely but the probem is even after the function ran and when I checked the cookie value in the browser it still shows there is no such cookie, i.e **The response.set_cookie is not working**.